# Want see all opend windows windows (inclusive icon and name) in task bar of KDE Neon 5.16

Tags: taskbar, kde

i cant find my opened Windows in

- KDE Desktop in Linux Distro
- KDE Neon 5.16 (rebased on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS).

I simply want to see all open apps on taskbar, all my windows (not grouped or anything special), inclusive it icon and name. all that means multi line if there to many, for e.g. 20 apps or so.

at the moment it looks like this:

[image]

[YT-Video: Problems with KDE Neon 5.16 - installed today - task menu dificult?](https://youtu.be/6WfqyGMVTrU)[2](https://youtu.be/6WfqyGMVTrU)

Comment: i deleted all panels deleted all tastmenu and build it new [live try with suggess](https://youtu.be/p8mPjr1gkYM). if it happens that only icons are visible edit panel and move it a bit up or down

Answer (score 0):

1. deleted all panels, all tastmanager
2. build it new

if it happens again that only icons are visible

then edit panel and move it a bit up or down.

it helps me while useing KDE Neon 5.16 ( [live try with success](https://youtu.be/p8mPjr1gkYM) )

Comment: if you know how to make this icons smaler please let me know

Comment: in kde neon 5.16 > task Manager settings > always arrange tasks in columns of as many rows